# Sql Error using GetDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I've tried "getdate" and "getdate() with no luck.

```
insert into Maintenance([MaintenanceNotes],[MaintenanceDate],[MaintenanceKey])
values ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<maintenancenote xmlns="http://www.metroalt.com/maintenancenote">
  <title>Wear and Tear on Hydralic units</title>
<note>
  <p>The hydralic units are showing signs of stress</p>
  <p>I recommend the replacement of the units</p>
</note>
  <followup>Schedule replacement for June 2016</followup>
</maintenancenote>', 'GETDATE', 'bus4')
```

Comment: I'd like to give you a little advise, because this is the second question of you, with the same query, where you just post errors you get:
Before you write a question here, try to find answers by seaching for the error message you get. It seems like you are a very beginner in sql. For that [the sql reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) is a great resource of information and there you would have immediately found, how to use `getdate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes, and use it as the actual function:

```
    insert into Maintenance([MaintenanceNotes],[MaintenanceDate],[MaintenanceKey])
    values ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <maintenancenote xmlns="http://www.metroalt.com/maintenancenote">
      <title>Wear and Tear on Hydralic units</title>
    <note>
      <p>The hydralic units are showing signs of stress</p>
      <p>I recommend the replacement of the units</p>
    </note>
      <followup>Schedule replacement for June 2016</followup>
    </maintenancenote>', GETDATE(), 'bus4')
```

For clarification, anything between two single quotes is considered as a text-string. `GETDATE()` is a function, so you need to ensure it is not wrapped in-between quotes.